# How to change my shell to real bash?

Tags: 13.04, command-line, bash

By typing `echo $0`, I know I'm using `tcsh` in my Ubuntu 13.04 terminal.
However no matter using `chsh -s /bin/bash` or just typing `bash` still can't make bash as my present shell. The interesting thing is that, if I type `sh`, then my shell will be `sh`. Finally I found a more interesting thing: each time after I typing `bash`, I type `ps` to see the change, I found I get two more lines: one is new bash PID, another is new tcsh PID, which means each time after I tried to use bash shell, system automatically change my shell back to tcsh immediately.
How can I solve this? Please help me!Thanks!

Comment: maybe your ~/.bashrc file contains a `csh` (or `tcsh`) command that's causing a new tcsh subshell to be spawned inside each bash shell? have you tried `grep csh ~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `echo $0`, you will get the name of the running process, the name of the file as was invoked on the command line, the name of the command currently being executed (see [Special shell variables](http://www.mcsr.olemiss.edu/unixhelp/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html)). The right command which will return your current shell where you are in is:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Therein lies probably your confusion. And yes, the right command to change your default shell is:

```
chsh
```

Better to use it without any arguments to see exactly what happens.

Comment: actually why i am aware of using tcsh not bash is because when I want to add a path, I have to type" sentev PATH=$PATH:." instead of "export .....".I tried to use "chsh" interactively, but doesn't work.  but I found the function of chsh is to change the default shell of login shell, but i am using non login shell. is this the reason it doesn't work? and I find, if I type" sudo -i" to be root user,then the shell become bash automatically. However in nonlogin shell, I can never change to bash.

Comment: @user2869734 What is the output of `cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER | cut -d":" -f7` command?

Comment: I'm so sorry of being so late. I get "/bin/bash" after I typed the command line you gave me. But now it seems i know the reason. Probably my professor installed tcsh on my laptop which is in /usr/bin, and in my PATH, i found /usr/bin this directory is in the front of /bin where -bash is. so after i deleted the tcsh, bash finally come back.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First type `cat /etc/shells` to see a list of available shells then use `chsh` to interact & change the shell. If you want to use it from a script use `chsh --shell SHELLNAME`.
I also suggest to read `/etc/login.defs` to see what you can customize, it's interesting & useful.
Have a nice day.